Bug with Clang 14 produces no object code when compiling c++ classes
I'm porting some code to c++ and I've started by writing a simple timer class for benchmarking.
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;


class run_timer {
private:
    steady_clock::time_point start_time;
    steady_clock::time_point split_time;
    
public:

    void start() {
        start_time = steady_clock::now();
        split_time = start_time;
    }

    double split() {
        steady_clock::time_point current_time = steady_clock::now();
        double elapsed_time = duration_cast<seconds>(current_time - split_time).count();
        split_time = current_time;
        return elapsed_time;
    }

    double stop() {
        steady_clock::time_point current_time = steady_clock::now();
        double elapsed_time = duration_cast<seconds>(current_time - split_time).count();
        return elapsed_time;
    }
};

When I compile it with g++ -c run_timer.cpp I get no errors and the resulting object file is 208 bytes.
00000000: cffa edfe 0700 0001 0300 0000 0100 0000  ................
00000010: 0200 0000 b000 0000 0020 0000 0000 0000  ......... ......
00000020: 1900 0000 9800 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 d000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0700 0000 0700 0000  ................
00000060: 0100 0000 0000 0000 5f5f 7465 7874 0000  ........__text..
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 5f5f 5445 5854 0000  ........__TEXT..
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 d000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0080 0000 0000  ................
000000b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 3200 0000 1800 0000  ........2.......
000000c0: 0100 0000 0000 0c00 0001 0d00 0000 0000  ................

The clang version is:
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

I've also got another c++ file with no class and it produces correct object file. If I wrap this file in a class it will produce an incorrect object file.
Is this a bug or is something else wrong with my build?

Looks like I got too used to Java and tried to put the implementation inside the class definition.  I had to remember that the implementation goes outside the class definition.
